# Simplest way to incorporate Python computations into web app

Tags: python, web-applications

My friend and I are developing a web app that allows the user drag and drop nodes and vertices to create a graph. The graph has a system of differential equations associated with it that we are using scipy, sympy, and matplotlib to solve and plot. The idea is that the user creates a graph, clicks a button, and the plot is displayed.

All of my research into Python and web apps has focused on creating the web app with Python (using frameworks like Django or Flask), but these aren't right for my purposes - we already have a web app that uses jsPlumb; all we need from Python is for it to return an image of the graph (for the main screen) and some strings (we're generating code that corresponds to the differential equations in Mathematica, LaTeX, MathML, etc.).

Can this be done inline - say, use the python file as a source and get what we needed returned? Should we be looking into some framework/tool? I'm not new to programming but this is my first time doing web development and I'm pretty clueless as to how to interface back-end and front-end, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's something stupid simple. Thanks!

**Important Note:** in the future we might allow them to change things about the graph (eg. edge weights) and have it update in real time so I'd like to keep the plot asynchronous.

Comment: what do you mean by "done inline"?  The browser doesn't (normally) know how to run python.  Unless your math is super-duper complicated I would think you could re-implement it in JavaScript, possibly running it asynchronously in a WebWorker to get proper asynchronousness.  Carefully written JS should be fairly close to python/C performance. If you want to do it on the server, then google "ajax frameworks" or "js mvc frameworks".  *Edit:* you can try "transpiling" C code to JS with emscripten

Comment: the math is pretty complicated, I'm actually using the scipy.integrate library from python (which runs compiled C code) to solve these equations, and sympy to convert the equations to the other formats, so I don't think there's a good replacement using purely javascript. Inline might have been a bad choice of words, I was trying to ask if I'd be able to just generate my plots on the server and get them over to the browser with simple commands or if I need to use a framework; from what you said I'll look at frameworks. Thanks!

Comment: I think I'm onto it using Django's templating language. Going to try using DTL in a separate file to generate some html then ship that over to the web page.